# How GNN layers can know which graph in a batch has the given node & node feature?

Tags: graph, pytorch

When we pass input as node features (x) and edge index (edge_index) to pytorch_geometric layer (e.g. GATConv), I am worried whether the layer can differentiate which batch sample the given node elements belong to.

x follows the shape [num of nodes, feature size] and edge_index follows shape [2, num of edges]. However, these 2 do not have the given information to know which input graph of batch size 32 have given node feature in the x.

Anyone can clarify on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyTorch-Geometric treats all the graphs in a batch as a single huge graph, with the individual graphs disconnected from each other. The node indices correspond to nodes in this big graph. This means there is no need for a batch dimension in `x` or `edge_index`.

Comment: That makes sense. Also I am wondering for my task of graph classification, I need to consider batch dimension and want Pytorch-geomtric to treat a batch input as individual graph for GCN layer. How can I do it ?

Comment: With tensors of sizes [batch_size,num of nodes, feature size] and [batch_size,2, num of edges] a GATconv layer does not work and returns an AssertionError regarding the static graph. It only works if one transforms the dimensions to [batch_size*num of nodes, feature size] and  [2, batch_size*num of edges]. However, how could pytorch geometric know that I merged several graph into a unique tensor?